# Improperly sending form data in html

Tags: javascript, html, fetch

So i would like to send Whatever i type in my input bar in to be sent to whatever api link via post method. But whenever i send it i get {} . The problem is when i dont send anything in the input bar A.K.A left blank and press submit i still get {}.  But when i type gibberish its still {} . So i assume whatever i typed in is not being sent to the api link.

Also when i hard code something like `body: JSON.stringify(this.myForm)` it shows up as a response in the back end. So i believe i error lies withing this body of my fetch request. heres my code what should i put for the body.

```
<html>

<body>
  <h1>Draft V0.1</h1>

  <form class="form" id="myForm">
    <label for="skill">add skill</label>
    <input type="text" name="skill" id="skill">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>

  <script>
    const myForm = document.getElementById('myForm')


    myForm.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      const formData = new FormData(this);

      fetch('https://fj5s3i60a8.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/updateSkill', {
        method: 'post',
        body: JSON.stringify(new FormData(myForm)),
        headers:
        {
          "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          "Accept": 'application/json'
        }
      }).then(function (response) {
        console.log(response)
        return response.json();
      });
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

- Note I was blindly playing around with the body to see what i can parse through it but i would end up getting cors errors.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

```js
const thisForm = document.getElementById('myForm');
thisForm.addEventListener('submit', async function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData(thisForm).entries()
    const response = await fetch('https://reqres.in/api/users', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify(Object.fromEntries(formData))
    });

    const result = await response.json();
    console.log(result)
});
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <h1>Draft V0.1</h1>

  <form class="form" id="myForm">
    <label for="skill">add skill</label>
    <input type="text" name="skill" id="skill">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>

  </body>

</html>
```